# /etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf Permission Denied

Tags: ubuntu-14.04

/etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf

What should I do to access this file

I want to change `DocumentRoot` **From** `/var/www/html` **To** `/var/www`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. First check to see who owns the file:

   ```
   ls -l /etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf
   ```

   It should probably be something like www-data.  For the rest of this answer I assume the user is www-data, replace it with the correct user on your system.
2. Verify you have permissions to act as that user, e.g.:

   ```
   sudo -u www-data id
   ```

   This command just runs the id command as the www-data user, you may have to enter a password.
3. Edit the file as the owner of the file:

   ```
   sudo -u www-data vi /etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf
   ```

   (or emacs or nano or whatever your favorite editor is).
4. If none of that works, the file permissions might be messed up, for example maybe the user of the file is not allowed to write to it.  In that case posting the output of:

   ```
   ls -l /etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf
   ```

   may be helpful in resolving your issue, but you probably can't go wrong by doing a:

   ```
   sudo -u www-data chmod o+rw /etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf
   ```

   This grants the owner read and write permissions on the file, then try the edit again.
5. If none of that works please post the exact command you are running, and the exact error message.

Comment: OK - then for your system this file is owned by root - for steps 2-5 you should replace www-data with root in the example, and step 4 will not be necessary for you.

Also - you may wish to verify root is the correct owner of this file by comparing the file owner of other files in the sites-available directory, and the owner of sites-available.  If they are all owned by someone other than root then perhaps there has been a mistaken ownership change.  If so you can change the owner back to whoever it should be with: sudo chown correct_owner /path/to/file

Answer (score 2):

You need to access this file as a root user. Issue the command

```
sudo -s
```

to get a root shell, then edit that file with the editor of your choice.

Answer (score -1):

Just run this command and you can edit that file

gedit admin:///etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf